# How to make expandable gallery showing images in computer version?

Tags: javascript, function, responsive-design, gallery

i'm trying to make an image gallery. In computer version you have all images visible, on mobile device you have 3 first pictures and the rest is shown after click on a button (you can hide it by clicking again). The problem is when I only shrink page to mobile and expand it for computers again it's ok, gallery works just fine. When I try to expand and hide images in mobile and after that come back to the computer version it shows only 3 images instead of whole gallery. How can I make it to automatically show all images when page is wider than 775px?

```
var col = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
var gbtnp = document.getElementById("gbtnp");

function gExpand() {
    for (i = 3; i < col.length; i++) {
        if (col[i].style.display === "block") {
        col[i].style.display = "none";
        gbtnp.style.transform = "rotate(0deg) translate(0, 10%)";
    } else {
        col[i].style.display = "block";
        gbtnp.style.transform = "rotate(-180deg) translate(0, 30%)";
    }
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a media query in javascript like this:

`var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 775px)");`

And you can check if `x` is true with the `matches()` function like this:

`x.matches()`

But this will only check once, so what you want to do is check if `x` is true every time the window is resized using an event listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        x.matches();
    }, true);
```

Also, you can always remove that event listener like this:

`window.removeEventListener('resize', Function, true);`

With this you can show or hide things based on the window with.
This works with any device so there's no problem for compability.

In your case I would do something like this.

```
var col = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
var gbtnp = document.getElementById("gbtnp");

var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 775px)");

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if(x.matches()){
       // Logic to show whole gallery
    }else{
       // Logic to show only 3 images
    } 
        
}, true);
```

I can't help you more because i don't know the logic behind your html and css, but it shouldn't be hard to figure it out. Good luck

Comment: Sorry, i'm a noob in js. Could you show how should it look like in my examlpe?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer to give you an example